# Responsive div layer with fixes height

Tags: html, css

How can I set a div layer to have e fixed height in pixels but in the same time this height to be responsive in smaller resolution ?

let's say the height of the div is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="size"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#size {

height:500px;

}
```

If I make the height 100% it will resize and it will be responsive. So why I need this to have fixed size and to be responsive in the same time, because the height I am using it for transition element which is happening to this div once clicked. So I would like to find out if there is a sollution of this problem.

Here is a FIDDLe example: http://jsfiddle.net/vladicorp/frNf5/

right now the style:

```
#index_slider
{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  float: left; 
  transition:all 1s ease;
  height:430px;

}
```

have fixed size, and it is not responsive but If I do it 100% height it is responsive but I am lusing the transition effect. This is the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `height` property in combination with `min-height`:

```
#size {
    height:100%;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

This will make your element stop resizing down when it reaches 500px height.

You can also use the `height` style in combination with the `max-height` style:

```
#size {
    height:500px;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

This will make it a fixed height of 500px, but if the container is resized down to less than 500 pixels, it will automatically start resizing with it.

Comment: it is not working, height element must stay 500px; in order to be calculated later in transition:all 1s ease;

Comment: @JohnSiniger so basically, you want it to always be 500px, but if the screen is smaller, become smaller too?

Comment: @JohnSiniger please see my edits. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I did edited the question with more information and Fiddle example of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px), only screen and (max-device-width: 980px) {
    /*
    PLACE CSS HERE
    */
}
```

Just choose whatever max-width you want depending on the device size. This will change the CSS depending on the size in pixel of the screen. (Or if you resize the window)

Comment: this will work but in the case of mobile device the transition effect will not be working.

Comment: because if the height of the #index_slider is not fixed number, it looks like it is not calculating it and the effect is just not working, the rezise transition which now it is working in the fiddle example.

Comment: The transition seems to be working perfectly fine on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frNf5/2/). It does the transition when bigger then 500px screen and keep 500px height while still doing the transition for smaller then 500px screen but having a responsive height

Comment: Yes the problem is that the on smaller resolution the slideshow is responcive but after it there is one space which is showing between the menu and the slide show, which space is because the fixed height, if this height is 100% it is responsive but the effect of scale is not working

Comment: Yes, but when clicked on a link the scale transition to stay of the slider closing from bottom to top.